# What is the Scan Direction of a satelite image?

Tags: metadata, satellite

There are two possible values that I am aware of for describing the scan Direction of a satellite capture:

1. Forward
2. Reverse

   - What is the meaning of  Forward and Reverse scan direction?
   - What are the pros and cons of each direction?
   - Provided I have a have choice should I favor one from the other? Which one?

Answer (score 2):

forward and reverse indicate where the sensor is capturing the information with respect to the displacement of the satellite. In other words, it will be forward if the satellite looks in front of him, and backward (or reverse) if he looks behind. For most applications, there are no pro and cons linked with either forward and backward, but this will obviously change the viewing azimuth angle, and hence the sun-object-sensor geometry. You could thus have more or less shadows and/or occlusion on your image depending on your choice. For minimum shadows, the sun and the satellite should have similar azimuth angles.